# How to setup OAuth2 token requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I’m searching for oaout/webapi best practices. I have following setup:

- A https://example.com –application for end clients (b2c)
- B https://admin.example.com – application for “partners” (b2b)
- C https://api.example.com – web api2 used by both domains secured with oauth

A and B are plain Angular application with no back-end code. In both cases you can create account and get oauth2 token via address  https://api.domain.com/oauth/token, but user logged in A should not be logged in B and vice versa. How to detect when user from A is putting his credentials on B and reject?

Possible solutions which are coming to my head:

- Pass application identifier in request
- Check referrer in request
- Other?